# What's the difference between $a^*+b^*$ and $(a+b)^*$?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

What's the difference between the regular expressions $a^*+b^*$ and $(a+b)^*$. Do both of these generate the same language? I was told in a lecture that $(a+b)^*$ will generate string concatenation of $a$ and $b$. How could this be possible?

Comment: What's the difference between $3^2+4^2$ and $(3+4)^2$? This is essentially the same question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby -24 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. $a^*+b^*$ generates words that either consist of any amount of $a$s or any amount of $b$s, like: $a$, $aaaaa$, $bbbb$
2. $(a+b)^*$ generates secquences of either $a$ or $b$, for example: $abab$, $aabb$, $bbaa$,...

So, the main difference is, that in 1 you either get strings only containing as or only containing bs. Regex 2 produces a language where you have no order of characters and can put both in.

So, both don't produce the same language, but 1 is a subset of 2.