# How does + symbol works in regular expression?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

[What's the difference between $a^*+b^*$ and $(a+b)^*$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45286/whats-the-difference-between-ab-and-ab)

I was going through this question. So according to the question-:

(a+b)* generates $\in$, a,b,ab,ba,aa,ba,...

whereas a*+b* generates $\in$, a,aa,aaa,b,bb,bbb etc.

Why can't a*+b* generate ab? What's stopping it from generating it? I feel like I am missing something fundamental. (Even if I take english meaning of word "OR", (a+b)* should generate same as a,aa,b,bb etc.)

I don't understand what's going on here. Please help me.

Comment: Have you ever seen a definition of the language generated by a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$ and $F$ are regular expressions then $E+F$ is also a regular expression that matches all words that are matched by at least one of $E$ and $F$.

In you case $E=a^*$, $F=b^*$, and $E+F=a^*+b^*$. The word $ab$ is not matched by $a^*+b^*$ since it is not matched by $a^*$ nor by $b^*$.

Comment: thank you. ok then how does (a+b)* accepts ab,ba etc? i mean a accepts a,aa,aaa...b accepts b,bb,bbb...a+b should accept a,b,aa,bb,aaa,bbb...then ??

Comment: `a` only matches $a$, `b` only matches $b$, `a+b` matches all and only the words in $\{ a, b\}$. `(a+b)*` matches any word consisting of the concatenation of any number (possibly $0$) of words in $\{ a, b\}$.

Comment: Thanks. so a matchs a,aa,aaa...b matches  b,bb,bbb so a+b matches a,aa,aaa...,b,bb,bbb...hence (a+b)* matches the combinations of them. (I think my confusion lies in what closure does. I know what it does, but I don't know definition of it, like how it performs).

Comment: No. `a` matches only $a$ (it does not match $aa$, $aaa$, $\dots$), and `b` matches only $b$.